# How to retrieve the number of distinct values from an excel column?

Tags: excel

I'm using this formula to calculate the number of distinct values on the column A:

```
=SUM(IF(1/COUNTIF(A:A; A:A)=1;1;0))
```

Problem is that it returns 0, but it's not true: I have put 40 different values.
What am I doing wrong?

**edit:**
It would seem the problem is the column: by doing COUNTIF(A1:A40;A1:A40) it works

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? The number of *unique* values in column A:A?

Comment: yes! I have edited the question: it would seem I can't apply the formula on all the column

Comment: Try this formula as array (Control + Shift + Enter) .. `=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)=1,A:A,0))`

Answer (score 1):

Use array formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(A:A; A:A);0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Clever formula. +1. What's the purpose of `IFERROR` here?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 ```IFERROR``` is for empty cells

Answer (score 0):

In a single formula, not so easy to get this information. With helper column, very simple.

In `B1`, type the following formula and drag down as far as your data goes:

```
= (COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1)+0
```

This returns `1` in the cell if its the first time this data was encountered in `A` column, otherwise turns 0. Then somewhere else use `SUM(B:B)` to get the number of unique values in the column.

If necessary, then you can hide the `B` column.